# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED for $cordova create

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I am very new to the world of npm and node.js.  I am trying to start a phonegap application and upon entering  $ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

I receive

Downloading cordova library for www...
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:896:19)

Has anyone had this problem and know a possible solution?  I am a n00b so I could be doing something very stupid - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the helloworld code you're trying to run?

Comment: O I may be misunderstanding.  I think this is supposed to generate a starting project. i.e. "hello" would be the generated folder containing the app with HelloWorld being the app title

Comment: It seems your error is easy to find by Googling - has none of those answers been useful?

Comment: Sort of.  I entered $phonegap -d create signature-closers com.signatureclosers SignatureClosers which https://www.marshut.net/kvqhxw/cordova-4-2-cli-returns-error-connect-econnrefused-phonegap-4-2-cli-works.html recommended.  However, I don't think I fully understand the issue or what this is trying to do.  After entering this command and rerunning the cordova create command I get a timeout error 


Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:896:19)

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine just had this problem.  Looks like he's on a newer version of node than I am (I'm on 0.10.32 and he's on 0.10.35).  I assume for this reason, he had a different setting for `strict-ssl` than I did (his was `false`, mine is `true`).  So I had him run:

`npm config set strict-ssl true`

And it solved the problem for him.  Hopefully this works for you too.